# How do I check if a word in a list contains at least a certain amount of a single letter

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python I  want to know if a list contains an item and how many.

For example, in:

```
sentence = "Paul sat in a tree and watched seven squirrels playing on the ground."
```

I wish to be able to pull out only words that contain two e's, printing out

```
["tree", "seven"].
```

Currently I have:

```
[x for x in sentence.split() if "ee" in x]
```

but that only outputs `["Tree"]` since I Assume it is only able to pick out words with two e's directly next to each other.

How would I do this so that it covers all e's within the elements no matter of where they are located?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it sounds like a homework problem

Comment: the Python `in` operator can be slightly surprising in this case. For a list it will find if an item belongs to a list: like `1 in [1, 2, 3]` returning True but won't be able to detect a sublist like `[1,2] in [1,2,3]` returning False. But in the case of a String the behavior is different it will look for a substring and `"ee" in "treecat"` will detect than "ee" is a substring of "treecat". Python doesn't provide a way to single out a character from a string anyway.

Comment: If you want to find if a word contains some definite list of letters (maybe different letters like "r" and "e" in "tree"), the `set` data structure and intersection of sets is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`count`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=count#str.count) to get the number of an element of a string

```
In [1]: data = "Paul sat in a tree and watched seven squirrels playing on the ground."

In [2]: [x for x in data.split() if x.count('e') > 1]
Out[2]: ['tree', 'seven']
```